# COM coclass implementing interface from another type library

Tags: com, idl, midl, coclass

I'm relatively new in COM, so appologies if this is a stupid question. I'm having a bunch of COM interfaces compiled into a type library *A*. This type library is a resource in one of the DLLs (*a.dll*) in my solution. In a separate type library (*B*) that goes into a separate DLL (*b.dll*) I would like to define a coclass that implements an interface from type library *A*. See the IDL code below as a simplified example of what I have in mind:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

// Import IMyInterface, which is part of MyLibA.tlb
import "MyInterface.idl";

[
    uuid(E80492A8-1E8C-4ABF-B4DE-9C252C445AFE),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("MyLibB Type Library")
]
library MyLibB
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    importlib("MyLibA.tlb); 

    [
        uuid(25E3CD5E-FA06-4845-BE3E-F260985AFB20),
        helpstring("My CoClass")
    ]
    coclass MyCoClass
    {
         [default] interface IMyInterface;
    };
};
```

I can compile the above ok, but when I open the tlb file generated by MIDL in oleview, I get an error message `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY`. I'm beginning to suspect what I want to do is not possible. My experimentation so far suggests that type libraries need to contain all the interfaces that a coclass implements along with the coclass definition itself. Is this true?

If I remove the `importlib("MyLibA.tlb);` statement, I can view the compiled tlb file in oleview without errors, but *MyLibB.tlb* then also contains the definition of the `IMyInterface` interface, i.e. the interface is defined twice in both type libraries. I don't want this because in my application I load both *a.dll* and *b.dll* using registration-free COM. In this scenario, the activation context generation fails when it encounters the same interface definition in more than one type library.

Any suggestions how I can achieve the desired interface and coclass separation in separate type libraries?

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I can now view the tlb of MyLibB.tlb in OLEView. The reason I hadn't registered MyLibA.tlb, was because I'm using registration free COM.

Comment: I have removed the comment and added it as an answer in case someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When OLE/COM viewer shows the `TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY` this typically means that another TLB which is referenced from the one which is being opened is not properly registered.

The fix is to register the dependency TLB (in this case MyLibA.tlb) with a tool like `regtlb` or `regtlib` or alternative, depending on your system.

As the question is given in the context of registration-free COM, you should be aware of possible issue with regard to marshaling of the interface instances. Typically, TLBs must be registered in order to use standard marshaller. Otherwise, you must make sure to properly declare marshaling info in your manifests, as mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx#rfacomwalk_topic8)

Comment: Yep, I thought the tlb was somehow corrupt because OLEView wouldn't open it but that was because MyLibA.tlb was not registered. I confirmed that in my registration free COM scenario I can use my coclass without either tlb being registered, I only need the registration for OLEView.

Comment: I have added a note to the answer, as you might have issues with marshaling since the tlbs are not registered.